# Is the function $f(x) =(\sum_{i=1}^{2}{|x_i|^{1/2}})^2$ , where $x=(x_1, x_2)\in {\mathbb{R^2}}$ a norm on $\mathbb{R^2}$?

Tags: metric-spaces, solution-verification, normed-spaces, triangle-inequality

$X=\mathbb{R^2}$ and $f:\mathbb{R^2} \to {\mathbb{R}}$ defined by $f(x) =(\sum_{i=1}^{2}{|x_i|^{1/2}})^2$ , where $x=(x_1, x_2)\in {\mathbb{R^2}}$.

Does the function $f$ define a norm on $\mathbb{R^2}$ ?

My attempt:

I) $f$ satisfy Positivity. i.e.
$f(x) \ge 0$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R^2}$.

II) Definiteness is also true. i.e $f(x) =0$ iff $x=0$.

III) $f(\lambda x)=|\lambda|f(x)$ , $\forall x\in \mathbb{R^2} $ and $\forall \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$

IV) I find a counter example for triangle inequality.

$x=(1, 0) $ and $y=(0, 1) $ , then $f(x+y) =(\sqrt{|1+0|}+\sqrt{|0+1|})^2=4$

$f(x) =(\sqrt{1+0})^2=1$

$f(y) =(\sqrt{0+1})^2=1$

$f(x+y) =4>1+1=f(x)+f(y)$

Hence, triangle inequality fails to hold for this two particular points $x$ and $y$.

Is this proof correct? How to think quickly that the triangle inequality doesn't holds? How to produce counter example quickly? Thanks.

Comment: Your proof is fine. You went about looking for a counterexample in the right way: first look at  simple but nontrivial examples.

Comment: Thank you. This really help me.

Comment: I, II, III are extra.